# Verification DisplayControl voice call button

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have found out that you can only have two actions in the display control - them being SendOTP and VerifyOTP (or something along those lines). Is there a way to add another button say "SendCall" for voice calls. I am using Twilio as the SMS gateway and would like to have a call me button just like the default MFA screen in B2C.

Whats the best way to achieve this?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Display Control only supports a single Send/Verify option currently. You could wire up these buttons to an API that makes a phone call OR an SMS.

Comment: Thanks, we have found a way to have a radio button to select mfa type and pass this to an api on the send button click. We this we now have voice and sms functionality on the display control.